# Access parent index in the child element in nested foreach in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var game_board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

(function plot() {
  game_board.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.forEach((value, j) => {
      // access i here
      console.log(j);
    });
  });
})()
```

I have a multidimensional array and I want to access both indexes i and j.

Comment: `// access i here` you should be able to access `i` there. Try `console.log(i, j)` and you'll see both indexes

Comment: Second loop is inside the first loop so i is accessible there were you want it

Comment: You can access i inside element foreach loop.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing ? did you tried accessing `i` ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually You have access:

```js
var game_board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

game_board.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.forEach((value, j) => {
      console.log('i : '+i+', j : '+j);
    });
  });
```

**Note:** function arguments of parent function is accessible by child function wherever the nested positions are. So, foreach callback function behaves in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Just for illustration:

```js
var game_board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

function plot() {
  game_board.forEach((element, i) => {
    element.forEach((value, j) => {
      // access i here
      console.log(j, i);
    });
  });
}

plot();
```